# Where can I find Spring Graph DB Tutorial Step-by-Step?

Tags: spring, neo4j

I'm new in Spring and I'm using it with Graph ORM module, I have searched around internet but just found a little code somewhere, there is no full tutorial guide me step by step from configuration to implement it using repository pattern.
Do you know any good tutorial about this ? Please give me some suggestions. Thanks alot !

Comment: I slightly edited tags and removed spring-mvc with java because spring-mvc is another project and question does not about java language (but about specific framework). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

There are [coding examples galore on github](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-graph-examples).  [Getting started guide](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-graph/blob/master/README.textile) can also be found in springsource project itself.  I am not sure what step-by-step you need, but any of those examples can be stripped bare, and pom.xml mildly modified -- e.g. your artifact id -- so as to provide you a template Spring-Neo4j project.

[edit per comment]:

[Hello-Worlds using Spring & Neo4j](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-graph-examples/tree/master/hello-worlds/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/examples/hellograph).

Comment: I did try that example, but it has a lot of code,seem it's not basic for new comer. Could you give me a template for enterprise project using Spring and its Graph DB ORM ?

Comment: 4 examples there. Just start with [HelloWorld](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-graph-examples/tree/master/hello-worlds).  (I don't believe ORM is correct usage here.  /Opinion/)

Comment: I don't believe it has reached the level of adoption by dev community that would require such a tutorial.

Comment: Chris perhaps you could look at the helloworld example and explain what else you need? What do you exactly mean by "enterprise project"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/pdf/spring-data-graph-reference.pdf) tutorial will suit your needs? It has a foreword by Rod Johnson and all!